# .html file in <welcome-file> throws 404 error while a .jsp file loads

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Go Scrapper</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>                                    
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>new.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I only use any one of the following when i run the program, when i use new.jsp, i get a page, but when i use index.html i get an error 404, both are in the same directory, (i.e) under WebContent/.

I have entered both here for ur understanding

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.go.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GoAnalyserDB" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="toor" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

hey guys, When the welcome file is a jsp then it loads the page, If i change it to a html, it hits me with a 404 error. I have checked with other codes. everything seems to be correct. I cant quite get what i have done wrong here.

Comment: I think your `jsp` file name is `index.jsp`  and where is your `jsp` file is located ?
you set wellcome file as `new.jsp` please check file name first.

Comment: The thing is when i set the welcome file as new.jsp, the welcome page loads, but when i set the welcome file as index .html .... it shows me a 404. Both files are present inside  WebContent/

Comment: I know that but what is your `jsp` file name ?

Comment: the jsp file name is new.jsp, The html file name is index.html

Comment: your jsp file is in "webapp" folder ?

Comment: yes, in the WebContent folder

Answer (score 0):

```
    i have tried following way and it's work.

    Spring config:

    <resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />

<beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </beans:bean>



    Controller method:

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String homePage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String returnText = "static/html/index";
        return returnText;
    }
```